# Vec::iter() converts to borrow of Option

Tags: rust

Below is an reduced example from my code that reads a directory, traverses over the files, and appends a comment to the end of each file...

This example shows a `Vec<Option<bool>>` that after calling `iter()` the compiler is interpreting the `Option<_>` as a borrow `&Option<_>` type. I'd like to understand why I'm seeing this behavior.

```
fn main() {
    let vec = vec![Some(true), None];

    vec.iter()
        .filter_map(|o| o)
        .count();
}
```

Compiler output

```
src/main.rs:50:25: 50:26 error: mismatched types:
 expected `core::option::Option<_>`,
    found `&core::option::Option<bool>`
(expected enum `core::option::Option`,
    found &-ptr) [E0308]
src/main.rs:50         .filter_map(|o| o)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Vec::iter`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter) returns an [`Iter`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html) struct, which implements `Iterator` as:

```
impl<'a, T> Iterator for Iter<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a T;
}
```

Said another way, the type of the value returned from each call to `Iterator::next` will be a reference to the item in the vector.

If you change to `vec.into_iter()`, your code works:

```
fn main() {
    let vec = vec![Some(true), None];

    vec.into_iter()
        .filter_map(|o| o)
        .count();
}
```

In this case, you are iterating on an [`IntoIter`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.IntoIter.html) struct which implements `Iterator` differently, returning the object itself:

```
impl<T> Iterator for IntoIter<T> {
    type Item = T;
}
```

This is required because only one thing may own each vector item at a time. Generally, you want to let the vector own the item and operate on references. `into_iter` *consumes* the vector, transferring ownership of the entire vector to the `IntoIter` struct. That struct is then allowed to give ownership of each item to the `filter_map` call.

If your type implements `Clone`, you could also clone each item. This allows the vector to maintain ownership and creates a new item:

```
fn main() {
    let vec = vec![Some(true), None];

    vec.iter()
        .cloned()
        .filter_map(|o| o)
        .count();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
fn main() {
    let my_vec = vec![Some(true), None];

    println!("{}", my_vec.iter().filter_map(|&x| x).count());
}
```

When apply `filter_map`, you can map `&x` to `x`, and your code will work.

As @Shepmaster pointed out in the comment this is only possible for types that implement `Copy`.